# How to compare two data sets with similar standard deviation and different type

Tags: t-test, standard-deviation, computational-statistics

I know my title is a little bit weird but here's an example.
I was working on a project about RPG game.

To be more simple, there are four values:

- physical - attack & defence
- magical - attack & defence.

I want to make a recommendation system for making a two-player party which has small standard deviation among those four values. From historical datasets, I found that the party would get higher chance of success if their standard deviation is low. Which means the party is well balanced.

So, My question is how to compare two different parties:

```
P1{(5,5,0,0),(0,0,5,5)
P2{(2,3,3,2),(3,2,2,3)}
```

I want to check if their difference of characteristics of two groups is meaningful or not. It is hard to sort by mathematical concept, but I can see definitely there are those groups.

Which test to use or how to compare both? I have no idea how to sort them and test them.

Answer (score -1):

[Chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) due to the variables being categorical